# JSON Web Tokens in Node Js Express application

Tags: json, node.js, api, express, json-web-token

So I have an API using Express in NodeJS and I want to secure it so only I or known clients can use it. I found about JSON Web Tokens but not sure how to keep the key secure if I'm making AJAX requests to the API from a web client using JQuery for example. People will be able to get the key and make request themselves right?

How do I prevent this? Or have I misunderstood the concept of JSON Web Tokens.

Other smaller question, I found the jsonwebtoken npm package which seems popular and you can sign a web token and verify one. How does the verification work? I know you pass a secret but the same secret is used for multiple signed keys right? I originaly thought I store the key in a database or something and verify if the provided key in the request is in my database but that does not seem to be the case as the you do not store the key.

Comment: The token has an expiration date in it. Unless you set the expiration date to never (which kinda defect the purpose), i don't think you need to worry about the case of sharing the token.

Comment: I would always want a token so if one expires how should I go about getting a new one? If I use an endpoint, it won't be protected and anyone could get a token and start using the API.

Comment: Generally speaking, instead of getting new token when the old one expires, you would want to refresh the token instead.

For example, you set the token to be expired in 30 min, but whenever the user does some kind of interaction to the web page, you refresh the token. You can do some logic there to reduce the frequency of refreshing the token too.

Normally, you create a new endpoint for refreshing the token. It will take a valid, not expired token, and returns a new token.